# How to expand or pass in variables to persistence.xml

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, rmi

I have two Glassfish servers each running an instance of my app. I want to enable cache coordination between them. In order to do this I need to configuration cache coordination in my persistence.xml file. The trouble is that value for the `eclipselink.cache.coordination.rmi.url` property needs to reference the box on which the app is running i.e., `rmi://myserver1:8686/`

I thought perhaps that persistence.xml could expand system properties but it seems that it can’t.

My JVM options contain:

```
-DCOORDINATION_RMI_URL=rmi://myserver1:8686
```

My persistence.xml file contains the following:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.rmi.url" value="${COORDINATION_RMI_URL}" />
<property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="com.foobar.conf.CacheCoordinationSessionCustomizer"/>
```

Then the logs complain with the following error:

```
[#|2014-05-28T16:40:59.688+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=136;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|[EL Warning]: 2014-05-28 16:40:59.685--ServerSession(1341405133)--Thread(Thread[Thread-60,5,grizzly-kernel])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-22102] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.RemoteCommandManagerException
Exception Description: Could not post connection in local naming service under name ${COORDINATION_RMI_URL}/01fa1eea-7ab2-4351-ab0b-4cf7b7f942f2
Internal Exception: java.net.MalformedURLException: invalid URL String: ${COORDINATION_RMI_URL}/01fa1eea-7ab2-4351-ab0b-4cf7b7f942f2
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.RemoteCommandManagerException.errorBindingConnection(RemoteCommandManagerException.java:89)
```

I’ve all tried setting a SessionCustomizer but it doesn’t seem to be able to change/set any properties, at least it doesn’t change the behaviour of the app.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.SessionCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Login;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;

public class CacheCoordinationSessionCustomizer implements SessionCustomizer {

    public void customize(Session session) throws Exception {
        JNDIConnector connector = null;
        Context context = null;
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
            if (context != null) {
                Properties p = System.getProperties();
                if(p.getProperty("COORDINATION_RMI_URL") != null) {
                    session.setProperty(PersistenceUnitProperties.COORDINATION_RMI_URL, p.getProperty("COORDINATION_RMI_URL"));
                    session.setProperty(PersistenceUnitProperties.COORDINATION_PROTOCOL, "rmi");
                    session.setProperty(PersistenceUnitProperties.COORDINATION_NAMING_SERVICE, "rmi");
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("_JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer: Context is null"); 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I could change the build process to change the persistence.xml file and create machine specific war files but this isn’t a valid solution since it doesn’t scale for n machines.

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink uses persistence properties to build a session object.  Once built, you use the session customizer to change the session directly - the properties are no longer used.

In the customizer, call `session.getCommandManager().setUrl(p.getProperty("COORDINATION_RMI_URL"));`